# Displaying an image on a ASP.NET (3.5) webpage, from a database

Tags: asp.net

I'm new to ASP.NET. I'm developing a site with ASP.NET 3.5 (VS 2008), and all I want to do is this:

1. Upload a image to the server (I'm doing this through FileUpload control)
2. Save the bytes (byte[]) in the database in some table
3. When user calls a page, say, Index.aspx?id=10, then I go a table, pull the relevant row which has id=10, the one of the cells has the image in the byte[] format
4. I now want to show this image on the webpage which has other things as well.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this - the image control only expects a URL and I don't want to save the image on the disk..

Any ideas please?

-Rick

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a class that implements the IHttpHandler interface.  Something like this should suffice:

```
public class ImageHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
{
  //code omitted

  public bool IsReusable
  {
    get
    {
      return (false);
    }
  } 

  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
  {
      //GetImageUrl is implemented elsewhere
      var imageURL = GetImageUrl(context.Request.Params["URL"]);

      //GetImageContentFromDatabase returns a structure with MIMEType and Content properties
      var imageData = GetImageContentFromDatabase(imageURL);

      if(imageData != null)
      {
        context.Response.ContentType = imageData.MIMEType;
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(imageData.Content);
      }
      else
      {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
      }
  }
}
```

You can place this class within your App_Code directory or, if you want to generalize this behavior, a separate assembly.

You can then reference this handler in your web.config file like so:

```
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="GET" path="*.imgx" type="ImageHttpHandler"/>
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

This implies that all get requests for files with extension imgx should be directed to the class ImageHttpHandler.

This will work well with Cassini (the Visual Studio Development Web Server), but you will need to make an additional change to your IIS website/virtual directory.

Go to the IIS MMC snap-in and access the properties of this directory.  You need to find the Configuration button which is housed within the "Virtual Directory" or "Home Directory" tabs.  Once there, add imgx as an application extension, set the executable to be aspnet_isapi.dll.  This is located, on my machine, at C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727.  Choose "All verbs" for simplicity, and uncheck "Verify that file exists."

The hyperlinks you define in your web pages should use the imgx extension.  Depending on your needs, you can define your links as "myimage.imgx" or "GetImage.imgx?id=XXX."  This depends on your needs and how you intend to retrieve the content of the image from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at that : [asp.net store image in sql and retrieve for aspimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698912/asp-net-store-image-in-sql-and-retrieve-for-aspimage/699048#699048)

Comment: Great answer, thanks David and Canavar. After thinking through this -- I'm wondering if I should save the hassle and just use the file system instead.

Comment: @rick s: the file system would be easier, but you have a couple of options with the database approach: (1) you don't have to worry about permissions in a networked environment, (2) you can play tricks with the content sent back (e.g., resize the image, apply effects, etc.), (3) There are some performance gains simply by being able to programmatically affect the response cache settings so that repeated requests are fed from the user's browser cache instead of from for your server.