# Unable to display image file from my database into the image control using generic handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need help in displaying  image file stored in my database into the 
image control. I've  read some articles and watched some video tutorials which  were perfectly working and I followed it but I wasn't able to make it work. The image control just displayes blank.I used Generic Handler to retrieve the image file from my database based. please help me to point out where did i went wrong?Thanks for any help...here is my code.

**Generic Handler**:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="ShowImage" %>

using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class ShowImage : IHttpHandler 
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.QueryString["ID"] == null) return;
        //string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ToString();
        string connStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Coldwind.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
        string ID = context.Request.QueryString["ID"];


        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
             using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Photos From ProfileTab Where ID =" + ID, conn))
             {
                 //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID",ID));
                 conn.Open();
                 using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                 {
                     reader.Read();
                     context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                     context.Response.BinaryWrite((Byte[])reader[reader.GetOrdinal("Photos")]);
                     // byte[] imgData = (byte[])reader["Photos"];
                     // context.Response.BinaryWrite(imgData);
                     reader.Close();
                 }
             }
         }
     } 


     public bool IsReusable
     {
         get
         {
             return true;
         }
     }

}
```

**Asp.Net Code for the Image control**:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "ShowImage.ashx?ID=" + Eval("ID") %>' Height="128px" />
```

Comment: not sure about this..... "reader.GetOrdinal("Photos")]"  need some code

Comment: I just used that as I saw in the video tutorial and it works perfectly on their end and don't why it's not working on my end since I followed it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try MemoryStream as this...

```
System.IO.MemoryStream dataStream = null;
dataStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(reader.GetOrdinal("Photos"));
context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
dataStream.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
dataStream.Close();
dataStream = null;
```

Comment: simply declare byte[] and debug to see if it has some value or blank try it

Comment: I tried to use codes like this but the same thing and Im sure it has data on it because my database column "Photos" shows <Binary Data>.

Comment: Here is my preivous codes I tried: context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                   context.Response.BinaryWrite((Byte[])reader[reader.GetOrdinal("Photos")]);byte[] imgData = (byte[])reader["Photos"];
                         context.Response.BinaryWrite(imgData);

Comment: try this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698912/asp-net-store-image-in-sql-and-retrieve-for-aspimage

Comment: or this one ....     http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/database/saving-retrieving-image-cs.aspx

Comment: @Prasad...I have tried so many codes including the codes you gave but still won't display the image.I just wander what I've been missing cuz these codes I used are working from the articles and video tutorials I read and I also tried changing my asp.net codes for the image control but still nothing happens.I'm stucked up with this.

Comment: 1 advise may work ..... try to debug application i think der may be one of these 2 problems.... 1) you get the byte[] wrongly due some issue with your function returning array or 2) array is correct but you can't see(render) image correctly