# Display an Image from Oracle 11g ex Database using Generic Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, blob, generic-handler

I have accomplished inserting an image into the Oracle database. Now I am trying to display it.

My handler code is :

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        OracleDataReader dr = null;
        OracleCommand cmd = null;
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVER_NAME=XE)));User Id=sakthi_studdb;Password=sakthi;");
        try
        {
            cmd = new OracleCommand
          ("select IMAGE from IMAGETBL where ID=" +
          context.Request.QueryString["imgid"], conn);
            conn.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
                context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["IMAGE"]);
            }
            if (dr != null)
                dr.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

And my aspx image control is :

```
    <div>
This is the student image requested:

    <asp:Image ID="picone" ImageUrl="~/Handler1.ashx?imgid=299" runat="server" />
</div>
```

When the run the aspx, I don't find any errors. But the image is not displaying. You can find the screen shot of the output I get below.

[image]

I want to know what is wrong.

```
     public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVER_NAME=XE)));User Id=sakthi_studdb;Password=sakthi;");
        try
        {
            long imageId = Convert.ToInt64(context.Request.QueryString["imgid"]);

            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select IMAGE from IMAGETBL where ID=:ID", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(":ID", OracleDbType.Int64).Value = imageId;
                conn.Open();
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
                context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            }                    

        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Even this din't work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698912/asp-net-store-image-in-sql-and-retrieve-for-aspimage

Comment: You should always use [*parameterized queries*](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html).This kind of codes are open for an [*SQL Injection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: put a break point in your handler and see did it reach there?

Comment: I tried adding a break point. It is fetching the handler code. This means it reaches there.

Comment: and you are getting the value from the database?

Comment: yes I am getting the values. I am not able to display the image only