# ASP.NET - Convert image data from SQL Server to image in listview

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, listview

I have a page to upload images to an image column in SQL Server and it converts it to binary... On another page I want to retrieve the images. I'm trying to do it like this in a listview:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr style="">
        <td>
            <img src='data:image/jpg;base64,<%# Eval("Image") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="ImageDescLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ImageDesc") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Am I doing something wrong? I figured it would be the best way to go about this.

The Image save code looks like this:

```
    void InsertImage()
    {
        byte[] theFile = new byte[FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength];
        HttpPostedFile file = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
        file.InputStream.Read(theFile, 0, (int)FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength);

        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null && FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName != "")
        {
            int result = new _Image()
                {
                    ImageName = txtFileName.Text,
                    ImageFile = theFile,
                    ImageDesc = txtDescription.Text
                }.AddImage();

            txtFileName.Text = "";
            txtDescription.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What really matters is the **ado.net** operations code.

Comment: @LeiYang I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: How can we talk about database without single line of related code?

Comment: What other code is necessary? I will post it. I need to convert from Image datatype from SQL Server to an image in the listview. Ive see where people do with data:image/jpg;base64, + binary data, so my question is, if this is retrieving binary data from the Image column, why doesn't it work the same way, am I missing something in the src= part?

Comment: Why not search and try before you ask, such as [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698912/asp-net-store-image-in-sql-and-retrieve-for-aspimage) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935205/retrieve-image-from-database-in-asp-net)

Comment: @LeiYang Those don't really apply to using it in a listview... Ive tried doing it that way.

Comment: can  you add the code of data save and retrieval and also what is they type of column of image in sql

Comment: @Usman Updated it with the save code. the type of column in sql is image and the retrieval is what I'm trying to figure out. I was hoping it would be as simple as what I posted originally but I'm running into problems with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use `byte[]` instead of `base64 string`

```
data:image/jpg;base64,<%# Eval("Image") %>
```

in this line  `Eval("Image")` will return a `byte array` which is not supported by `html` you can you  `Convert.ToBase64String(img)` img should be `byte[]`

Comment: Would I add that when inserting the image to the database? or after? if after, where would you put that?

Comment: it will be after when you retrieve the image from database because it will convert from binary

Comment: if you are having issue you can paste the sql code for data retrival

Comment: The sql is nothing more than  SELECT Image,
     ImageDesc
 FROM dbo.Images

How would I set the value of img from the img field in the listview?

Comment: `<%# Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("Image"))  %>`  try this

Comment: Yes that's it! Had to keep this in there though `data:image/jpg;base64,<%# Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("Image")) %>`